# How to force a ListView to display in the same row two diffrent data from differnt elements of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, code-behind

In my xaml file, I have a this ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" HasUnevenRows="true">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemplate">
                     <ViewCell>
                         <FramePadding="2" BorderColor="DarkSlateGray">
                             <Grid x:Name="grid" Padding="0">
                                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="1.6*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                                 <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >
                                     <Label.FormattedText>
                                         <FormattedString>
                                             <Span TextDecorations="Underline" TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding dateName}"/>
                                             <Span Text="{x:Static system:Environment.NewLine}"/>
                                             <Span Text="{Binding date}"/>
                                         </FormattedString>
                                     </Label.FormattedText>
                                 </Label>
                                 <Label Grid.Column="{Binding gridNumber}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
                                     <Label.FormattedText>
                                         <FormattedString>
                                             <Span TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding Information}"/>
                                         </FormattedString>
                                     </Label.FormattedText>
                                 </Label>
    
                                 <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                 <BoxView IsVisible="{Binding IsSimpleSeance}" BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="1" Grid.Column="{Binding gridNumber}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                 <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                 <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                                 <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="1" Grid.Column="5" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                 <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" WidthRequest="1" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                             </Grid>
                         </Frame>
                     </ViewCell>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
```

And in my ViewModel file, I had this ObservableCollection:

```
 lObservableCollectionist<MyObject> MyList = [
  {"Monday", "07/12", "Some Data in First Line", 1},
  { "Monday", "07/12", "Some Other Data ALSO in First Line",4},
  { "Tuesday", "08/12", "New Data in Second Line" ,1},
  { "Tuesday", "08/12", "New Other Data in Second Line",4 },
  { "Tuesday", "08/12", "Newest Data Also in Second Line",6 },
   ...
   ]
```

So, the problem is the ListView display each element of the ObservableCollection in new line like this !
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbIcw.png)
But what I want is to group the same day data in one line. Something like this

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGFiR.png)

Comment: ListView won't do this.  A Grouped CollectionView may get you closer, but I think you're going to need to write a custom control to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you Jason for the comment!
I am using MVVM architecture! this is why I am trying avoid writing code in the code behind.

Comment: nothing I suggested requires breaking MVVM

Comment: I am beginning to know the xamarin and MVVM.. so I read in some forms that I must avoid to the maximum writing code in the behind code ... thanks for the clarification !

Comment: You just need reconstruct your list as described below.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instead of a one label , you can add multiple labels and map each label with each column and change your Information property
and remove <strike>**gridNumber**</strike> property

**Your Model**

```
public class MyObject
{
    ...
    public string InformationColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string InformationColumn2 { get; set; }
    public string InformationColumn3 { get; set; }
    public string InformationColumn4 { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

**Xaml**

```
...
<!-- Remove grid number binding and add label for each column-->
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding InformationColumn1}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
<Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding InformationColumn2}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
<Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span TextColor="Black"  Text="{Binding InformationColumn3}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
...
```

P.S. You can further set a [CONVERTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to `IsVisible` property of all `Label` so that it is only visible only when the InformationColumn data is not null.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
the problem is that I don't know the data I'm going to show in my ListView !
For exemple in the first row that is represting MONDAY, I had 2 informations with specific position in the Grid for each one, and in other case I have in Monday row only one information with other position in the grid! 
PS: the image that i posted with the quastion could help more to understand what I try to say .

Comment: If you dont know the data , you can convert the data after you have received the response. create a method to merge all rows with same date, and convert the old list with new list